# embed Video Display in SWT/RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp, mjpeg

How to display a video (or mjpeg) in a SWT/RCP aplication while the video must has as less as possible impact from the other UI interation?

At moment I paint MJPEGs in a Canvas wihtin UI Thread, and it will lag when I did other UI interactions.
Is there possible to draw video or motion images independent from other UI interactions?

thanks!!

Comment: Could you post some code with the part of movie playing and the MJPEG file..?

Comment: Actually I used http://www.charliemouse.com/code/cambozola/index.html

Comment: Could you post the code of canvas rendering?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to display MJPG of a Webcam you chould use the [Browser-Widget](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.html). I guess it is also possible to display other formats like mp4 in a browser.

Here you can find a SWT Example to -> [render HTML from memory](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet136.java)

Some useful HTML-Code to display a MJPG Webcam:

```
<html><head></head>
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
<img src="http://the.hostname/video?camera=1">
</body>
</html>
```